# How to define a type of return based on an argument string? Flowtype javascript

Tags: javascript, flowtype, ecmascript-next

For example I got this fn:

```
const aCar = {type: 'car', wheels: 4};
const aBike = {type: 'bike', wheels: 2};

const fn = (type:'a'|'b'):Car|Bike => {
  if(type === `a`) return aCar;
  if(type === `b`) return aBike;
}
```

The problem is that the return is always `Bike` or a `Car` indipendently of the type. I would like to enforce that when the type is `a` the return is always of type `Car` and when is `b` the type to be `Bike`.

Is this possible?

Something [very close](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqAltgKYC2moAvKANoCMANKAEwMDMAugNzLYCeADoVAAxPACccAFX6DKAClkB9AFygA5AENVASgoA+UOgCuxAEaFROgGSh56FapPa9oAIKjR6ngB4jp87q0uVAwcUEgxHBURcWwpAQobdC0ldXQeZwBvRFB8SESKckoAInUinSycnNFCbENRdHwiUioABk5s0ABfUEJoTEE8SFkGwsoHJwrQAEhq2vrGkkwuHM7EVeCsXHUVXzNRBPCY2Q1tLjRN0BMVNw9vXf8DiOxjx0CgA):

```
// @flow

const items = [1, 2, 3];

type FirstType = ((_: 'a') => number) & ((n: 'b') => Array<number>);

const first: FirstType = (n):any => {
  if (n === "a") {
    return items[0];
  } else if(n === 'b') {
    return items;
  }
}

const a: number = first('a');
const b: Array<number> = first('b');
```

Thanks

Comment: use [generics](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/)?

Comment: Generics only work if the input is the same type as output. In this case the input is a string `'a'` and output is an object. The mapping between the input and the output has to be done in the `fn` not in the parent because there is no way the parent to know how to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do what I need to with this code. Is overloading the function and then uses the argument as an object to define the return. Is quite OK solution but could be better.

Note: the argument of `formatNotification` can only be an object and not 2 arguments like `formatNotification(type, data)`.

Still not a good solution but halfway working.

[image]

And the types:

[image]